# Is there a way to set a default http header for all static files in app.yaml without repetition?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an app.yaml files with a bunch of different static file directives, such as

```
- url: /sitemap.xml
  static_files: public/sitemap.xml
  secure: always
  upload: public/sitemap.xml
  http_headers:
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
    Feature-Policy: microphone 'none'; notifications 'none'
    Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; font-src fonts.gstatic.com ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com
```

Now, I really don't want to bloat up the app.yaml file with tens of copies of the http headers for every static file or path I serve. Is it possible to specify a global header directive that is used for all static paths served ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE does not allow anchors in app.yaml.  Otherwise, you could do something like:

```
runtime: python37       
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT application:app --timeout 36000

headers: &headers
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
  Feature-Policy: microphone 'none'; notifications 'none'
  Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; font-src fonts.gstatic.com ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com

handlers: 
- url: /sitemap.xml
  static_files: public/sitemap.xml
  secure: always
  upload: public/sitemap.xml
  http_headers: *headers
```

If you deploy using the Admin API (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/deploying-overview), you could use the above `app.yaml`, but convert it to an `app.json` (e.g. https://www.convertjson.com/yaml-to-json.htm), which converts the above yaml code with the anchors into the longer version:

```
{
   "runtime": "python37",
   "entrypoint": "gunicorn -b :$PORT application:app --timeout 36000",
   "headers": {
      "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
      "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
      "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
      "Referrer-Policy": "no-referrer",
      "Feature-Policy": "microphone 'none'; notifications 'none'",
      "Content-Security-Policy": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; font-src fonts.gstatic.com ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com"
   },
   "handlers": [
      {
         "url": "/sitemap.xml",
         "static_files": "public/sitemap.xml",
         "secure": "always",
         "upload": "public/sitemap.xml",
         "http_headers": {
            "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
            "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
            "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
            "Referrer-Policy": "no-referrer",
            "Feature-Policy": "microphone 'none'; notifications 'none'",
            "Content-Security-Policy": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; font-src fonts.gstatic.com ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Probably not what you were hoping for, but putting it out there.

Comment: Thanks! That's super helpful; didn't even know about the admin api.

I can also look into 'hugo deploy" and see if there's anything helpful there. Truth is, I want to deploy a site that is mostly hugo with some extra server side code. So I first run "hugo" to rebuild the static content and then deploy the app together with static content. Maybe I should figure out how I can tease apart the static and dynamic stuff.